# How to remove article ID from url in Joomla 1.5?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

Using standard SEF in Joomla 1.5 I have links like: `mysite.com/news/36-good-news-tooday`.
I need to remove article ID from url and get something like this: `mysite.com/news/good-news-today`.

**Note:** It means I don't want use any plugins (like HP Router etc.)
I want edit Joomla own SEF.

**UPD:** Finally I found desicion. Here is full listing of router.php, wich you can find in `components/com_content`

```
<?php
/**
* @version      $Id: router.php 14401 2010-01-26 14:10:00Z louis $
* @package      Joomla
* @copyright    Copyright (C) 2005 - 2010 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
* @license      GNU/GPL, see LICENSE.php
* Joomla! is free software. This version may have been modified pursuant
* to the GNU General Public License, and as distributed it includes or
* is derivative of works licensed under the GNU General Public License or
* other free or open source software licenses.
* See COPYRIGHT.php for copyright notices and details.
*/

function ContentBuildRoute(&$query)
{
    $segments = array();
$menu = &JSite::getMenu();
if (empty($query['Itemid'])) {
    $menuItem = &$menu->getActive();
} else {
    $menuItem = &$menu->getItem($query['Itemid']);
}
$mView  = (empty($menuItem->query['view']))? null : $menuItem->query['view'];
$mCatid = (empty($menuItem->query['catid']))? null : $menuItem->query['catid'];
$mId    = (empty($menuItem->query['id']))? null : $menuItem->query['id'];

if(isset($query['task'])) {
    return $segments;
}

if(isset($query['view']))
{
    $view = $query['view'];
    if(empty($query['Itemid'])) {
        $segments[] = $query['view'];
    }
    unset($query['view']);
};

if (($mView == 'article') and (isset($query['id'])) and ($mId == intval($query['id']))) {
    unset($query['view']);
    unset($query['catid']);
    unset($query['id']);
}

if (isset($view) and ($view == 'section' && !empty($query['Itemid']))) {
    if (($mView != 'section') or ($mView == 'section' and $mId != intval($query['id']))) {
        $segments[] = 'section';
        unset($query['Itemid']);
    }
}

if (isset($view) and $view == 'category') {
    if ($mId != intval($query['id']) || $mView != $view) {
        $temp = explode(':',$query['id']);
        if(count($temp) > 1)
        {
            $query['id'] = $temp[1];
        }

        $segments[] = $query['id'];
    }
    unset($query['id']);
}

if (isset($query['catid'])) {

    if ((($view == 'article') and ($mView != 'category') and ($mView != 'article') and ($mCatid != intval($query['catid'])))) {
        $temp = explode(':',$query['catid']);
        if(count($temp) > 1)
        {
            $query['catid'] = $temp[1];
        }

        $segments[] = $query['catid'];
    }
    unset($query['catid']);
};

if(isset($query['id'])) {
    if (empty($query['Itemid'])) {
        $temp = explode(':',$query['id']);
        if(count($temp) > 1)
        {
            $query['id'] = $temp[1];
        }

        $segments[] = $query['id'];
    } else {
        if (isset($menuItem->query['id'])) {
            if($query['id'] != $mId) {
                $temp = explode(':',$query['id']);
                if(count($temp) > 1)
                {
                    $query['id'] = $temp[1];
                }

                $segments[] = $query['id'];
            }
        } else {
            $temp = explode(':',$query['id']);
            if(count($temp) > 1)
            {
                $query['id'] = $temp[1];
            }

            $segments[] = $query['id'];
        }
    }
    unset($query['id']);
};

if(isset($query['year'])) {

    if(!empty($query['Itemid'])) {
        $segments[] = $query['year'];
        unset($query['year']);
    }
};

if(isset($query['month'])) {

    if(!empty($query['Itemid'])) {
        $segments[] = $query['month'];
        unset($query['month']);
    }
};

if(isset($query['layout']))
{
    if(!empty($query['Itemid']) && isset($menuItem->query['layout'])) {
        if ($query['layout'] == $menuItem->query['layout']) {

            unset($query['layout']);
        }
    } else {
        if($query['layout'] == 'default') {
            unset($query['layout']);
        }
    }
};

return $segments;
}

function ContentParseRoute($segments)

{
    $vars = array();

$menu =& JSite::getMenu();
$item =& $menu->getActive();
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$count = count($segments);


if(!isset($item))
{
    $vars['view']  = $segments[0];
    $vars['id']    = $segments[$count - 1];
    if($vars['view'] == 'article')
    {
        $query = 'SELECT id FROM #__content WHERE alias = '.$db->Quote($vars['id']);
    } elseif($vars['view'] == 'category') {
        $query = 'SELECT id FROM #__categories WHERE section > 0 && alias = '.$db->Quote($vars['id']);
    }
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $vars['id'] = $db->loadResult();
    return $vars;
}

switch($item->query['view'])
{
    case 'section' :
    {
        if($count == 1) {
            $vars['view'] = 'category';

            if(isset($item->query['layout']) && $item->query['layout'] == 'blog') {
                $vars['layout'] = 'blog';
            }
        }

        if($count == 2) {
            $vars['view']  = 'article';
            $vars['catid'] = $segments[$count-2];
        }

        $vars['id']    = $segments[$count-1];

    } break;

    case 'category'   :
    {
        $vars['id']   = $segments[$count-1];
        $vars['view'] = 'article';

    } break;

    case 'frontpage'   :
    {
        $vars['id']   = $segments[$count-1];
        $vars['view'] = 'article';

    } break;

    case 'article' :
    {
        $vars['id']   = $segments[$count-1];
        $vars['view'] = 'article';
    } break;

    case 'archive' :
    {
        if($count != 1)
        {
            $vars['year']  = $count >= 2 ? $segments[$count-2] : null;
            $vars['month'] = $segments[$count-1];
            $vars['view']  = 'archive';
        } else {
            $vars['id']   = $segments[$count-1];
            $vars['view'] = 'article';
        }
    }
}

$alias = explode(':', $vars['id']);
if((int) $alias[0] > 0)
{
    $vars['id'] = $alias[0];
} else {
    if(count($alias) > 1)
    {
        $vars['id'] = $alias[0].'-'.$alias[1];
    }

    if($vars['view'] == 'article')
    {
        $query = 'SELECT id FROM #__content WHERE alias = '.$db->Quote($vars['id']);
    } elseif($vars['view'] == 'category') {
        $query = 'SELECT id FROM #__categories WHERE section > 0 && alias = '.$db->Quote($vars['id']);
    }
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $vars['id'] = $db->loadResult();
}

return $vars;
}
```

I'm not an author! Router code was modified by [Marvin Ryan](http://joomlavisually.com/main/48-tips-and-tricks/5438-remove-joomla-articles-id.html).

This code works perfect in most of cases!
But I have some problems with JoomFish language toggle.
It have links like `www.mysite.com/news/22`
So I get only article ID, not article alias. This problem is still actual!

Answer (score -1):

Create menu items for every article.

Comment: Sorry, but this method not works for me. I have more then 1000 articles, so I believe it not the best way to create menus for every of them.

Comment: I did not say it was practical but the fact is that is how you do it. When you have a menu item you do not get the id in the url.

Alternatively: make a menu item for each of your top level categories. This does not need to be on a menu that you display, just one you create.  This will then apply the menu item information to every article and category within each of the categories. The downside is that you will get urls that include the category structure which may not be what you want. Depending on the urls you are looking for you could make a menu item for each category.

Comment: Actually my comment applies more for 2.5/3 but the principle is the same in 1.5. In 1.5 make  a menu item for each section.

Comment: Creating menu items for every section only solves the problem with indexes of categories, but article indexes still stay. Maybe your decision works good for 2.5, but I sure I need change standard SEF in 1.5. I already did this, but now I have some problems with JoomFish language toggle links...

Comment: Just update my question. I hope it helps other people to solve the same problem ;)